# Operation over several columns

Tags: excel, operation

I am wondering , if I can write a formula which would operate over several columns, e.g. I want to calculate the amount of males in the school and I have a table:

```
A     B        C
Class Sex      Number
1     male     3
2     male     4
1     female   6
2     female   5
```

Right now I have to break the operations into parts:

```
=(B2="Male")*C2 - additional column and then 
=SUMME(D2:D5)
```

I want to do it at once. It seems like a trivial functionality, but I can not figure it out, how I can do it in one formula.

Comment: Array formulas might help: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Comment: maybe `=sumifs(c:c, b:b, "male")` or `=SUMMEWENNS(c:c, b:b, "male")`